# Outputting elements from the list except first n elements

Tags: list, recursion, f#

How do you write a F# recursive function that accepts a positive integer `n` and a list `xs` as input, and returns a list except first `n` elements in `xs`?

```
let rec something n xs = .. something 7 [1..10] = [8; 9; 10]
```

Comment: You just need to call your recursive function N times ignoring the head of your list. When that is done - the remainder of the list is what you are looking for. Have you tried to implement something?

Comment: You return the list if n = 0, otherwise return something of n-1 and tail of xs.
But why recursively? Use Seq.skip

Comment: Also partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333766/why-there-is-no-list-skip-and-list-take

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that recursion is the most efficient way to solve this problem, but you can do it like this:

```
let rec something n xs = 
    if n > List.length xs || n < 0 then failwith "incorrect parameter n - out of range"
    else if n = 0 then xs
    else something (n-1) (xs |> List.tail)

let res = something 7 [1..10]

open System
Console.WriteLine(res)
//something 7 [1..10] = [8; 9; 10]
```

Comment: Will fail on `List.tail` with "The input list was empty.Parameter name: list" if `n` is greater than the list length.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use `List.skip` ... i.e. `[0..10] |> List.skip 5`

To reimplement `List.skip` you'd be looking at something like:

```
let rec listSkip n list =
    match (n, list) with
    | 0, list                 -> list
    | _, []                   -> failwith "The index is outside the legal range"
    | n, _ when n < 0         -> failwith "The index cannot be negative"
    | n, _ :: tl              -> listSkip (n - 1) tl
```

As this is recursion is eligible for tail-call optimization, performance should be similar to an explicit loop.

I've avoided an explicit guard checking `List.length` against `n` because `List.length` requires iteration of the entire list ( which we'd have to check each round of the recursion ). Thus it's cheaper just to try and remove `n` items and fail if we run into an empty list before `n` reaches `0`.